# use underscore inside lstlisting with python

Tags: beamer, lstlisting

I'm using lstlistigs to show python code in beamer, but when I try to write the sentence: bbox_to_anchor:

```
bbox\_to\_anchor
```

don't show the first underscore, only the second.

In my lstlisting style I have:

```
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{brown}{rgb}{0.59, 0.29, 0.0}
\definecolor{OliveGreen}{rgb}{0,0.25,0}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{0.98\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Código}
\definecolor{Code}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{Keywords}{rgb}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{Strings}{rgb}{255,0,255}
\definecolor{Comments}{rgb}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{Numbers}{rgb}{255,128,0}
\makeatletter
\newif\iffirstchar\firstchartrue
\newif\ifstartedbyadigit
\newif\ifprecededbyequalsign
\newcommand\processletter
{%
 \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
 \iffirstchar%
    \global\startedbyadigitfalse%
  \fi
  \global\firstcharfalse%
\fi
}

 \newcommand\processdigit
 {%
 \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
  \iffirstchar%
    \global\startedbyadigittrue%
  \fi
  \global\firstcharfalse%
  \fi
}

\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}%
{%
\lst@IfLastOtherOneOf{=}
{\global\precededbyequalsigntrue}
{}%
}

\lst@AddToHook{Output}%
{%
\ifprecededbyequalsign%
  \ifstartedbyadigit%
    \def\lst@thestyle{\color{orange}}%
  \fi
\fi
\global\firstchartrue%
\global\startedbyadigitfalse%
\global\precededbyequalsignfalse%
}

\lstset{ 
language=Python,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\scriptsize,
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=5pt,
backgroundcolor=\color{white},
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
frame=single,
tabsize=2,
captionpos=t,
breakatwhitespace=false,
escapeinside={\#},
stringstyle =\color{OliveGreen},
keywordstyle = \color{blue},
commentstyle = \color{black},
identifierstyle = \color{black},
literate=%
     {á}{{\'a}}1
     {é}{{\'e}}1
     {í}{{\'i}}1
     {ó}{{\'o}}1
     {ú}{{\'u}}1
}

\lstdefinestyle{FormattedNumber}{%
literate={0}{{\textcolor{red}{0}}}{1}%
         {1}{{\textcolor{red}{1}}}{1}%
         {2}{{\textcolor{red}{2}}}{1}%
         {3}{{\textcolor{red}{3}}}{1}%
         {4}{{\textcolor{red}{4}}}{1}%
         {5}{{\textcolor{red}{5}}}{1}%
         {6}{{\textcolor{red}{6}}}{1}%
         {7}{{\textcolor{red}{7}}}{1}%
         {8}{{\textcolor{red}{8}}}{1}%
         {9}{{\textcolor{red}{9}}}{1}%
         {.0}{{\textcolor{red}{.0}}}{2}% Following is to ensure that only periods
         {.1}{{\textcolor{red}{.1}}}{2}% followed by a digit are changed.
         {.2}{{\textcolor{red}{.2}}}{2}%
         {.3}{{\textcolor{red}{.3}}}{2}%
         {.4}{{\textcolor{red}{.4}}}{2}%
         {.5}{{\textcolor{red}{.5}}}{2}%
         {.6}{{\textcolor{red}{.6}}}{2}%
         {.7}{{\textcolor{red}{.7}}}{2}%
         {.8}{{\textcolor{red}{.8}}}{2}%
         {.9}{{\textcolor{red}{.9}}}{2}%
         {\ }{{ }}{1}% handle the space
     ,%
      escapeinside={__}
      }
```

In my document.tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\input{../Preambulos/pre_codigo}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain, allowframebreaks, fragile]
\frametitle{Código para la solución}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Código para el método de disparo, style=FormattedNumber, basicstyle=\linespread{1.1}\ttfamily=\small, columns=fullflexible]
plt.plot(x,y_1_[:,_0_],'r+', label='solucion con alfa de prueba')
plt.plot(x,exacta(x),'b-', label='solucion exacta')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('u(x)')
plt.title('Metodo de disparo con $\alpha = 1.0$')
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.axhline(y = 0, color='k', lw=0.75, ls='dashed')
plt.legend(loc='lower left', bbox\_to\_anchor=(0.5, 0.35))
plt.show()
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Then, when I compile the latex file, get this:

[image]

I hope all the information goes!

Thanks in adavance again!!

Gustavo.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you use `_` as escape character. To circumvent this problem, you could use your escape characters and input the underscores via latex code as `\textunderscore`. Or you could use some other escape character.

Please also note that you don't need `xcolor` and `color` with beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{color}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Código}
\definecolor{Code}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{Keywords}{rgb}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{Strings}{rgb}{255,0,255}
\definecolor{Comments}{rgb}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{Numbers}{rgb}{255,128,0}

\lstset{ 
language=Python,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\scriptsize,
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=5pt,
backgroundcolor=\color{white},
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
frame=single,
tabsize=2,
captionpos=t,
breakatwhitespace=false,
escapeinside={\#},
stringstyle =\color{OliveGreen},
keywordstyle = \color{blue},
commentstyle = \color{black},
identifierstyle = \color{black},
literate=%
     {á}{{\'a}}1
     {é}{{\'e}}1
     {í}{{\'i}}1
     {ó}{{\'o}}1
     {ú}{{\'u}}1
}

\lstdefinestyle{FormattedNumber}{%
literate={0}{{\textcolor{red}{0}}}{1}%
         {1}{{\textcolor{red}{1}}}{1}%
         {2}{{\textcolor{red}{2}}}{1}%
         {3}{{\textcolor{red}{3}}}{1}%
         {4}{{\textcolor{red}{4}}}{1}%
         {5}{{\textcolor{red}{5}}}{1}%
         {6}{{\textcolor{red}{6}}}{1}%
         {7}{{\textcolor{red}{7}}}{1}%
         {8}{{\textcolor{red}{8}}}{1}%
         {9}{{\textcolor{red}{9}}}{1}%
         {.0}{{\textcolor{red}{.0}}}{2}% Following is to ensure that only periods
         {.1}{{\textcolor{red}{.1}}}{2}% followed by a digit are changed.
         {.2}{{\textcolor{red}{.2}}}{2}%
         {.3}{{\textcolor{red}{.3}}}{2}%
         {.4}{{\textcolor{red}{.4}}}{2}%
         {.5}{{\textcolor{red}{.5}}}{2}%
         {.6}{{\textcolor{red}{.6}}}{2}%
         {.7}{{\textcolor{red}{.7}}}{2}%
         {.8}{{\textcolor{red}{.8}}}{2}%
         {.9}{{\textcolor{red}{.9}}}{2}%
         {\ }{{ }}{1}% handle the space
     ,%
      escapeinside={__}
      }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}[style=FormattedNumber]
bbox_\textunderscore_to_\textunderscore_anchor
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```